# comparing consecutive rows in awk

Tags: awk, compare

I would like to compare consecutive rows in a file using awk command. Here is an example of input and output.

Input file

```
6    
7    
8    
9    
10    
4    
5    
6
```

The output file I wanted to have is like this:

```
6
7
8
9
10 
14 
15 
16
```

Basically I wanted to compare if the current line is greater than the previous one and continue to print both the previous and the current lines. As soon as the current line is less than the previous one, add a value (10) to each of the subsequent lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated as per request in comment**:

```
awk '{if ($1<prev) {offset++}; print ($1+(offset*10)); prev=$1}' input_file
```

This will now increase the increment offset by 10 each time you go from a larger number to a smaller number between consecutive lines.

Comment: Thank you. I have now a second case that I have to add not only (10) for the first case but now I have to add (20) for the second case):                                                                        input file                                                          6  7  8  9  10 | 4  5  6 | 1  2  3                                                    output                                                                                                                                       6 7 8 9 10 | 14 15 16 | 21 22 23

Comment: @Yacob see updated answer. this will do it for 30, 40, 50 ... etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$0<p{$0+=10} {p=$0} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to save the prior value in a variable and compare with that:

```
awk '{ if ($0 < old) { $0 += 10; } print; old = $0; }'
```

Comment: In the context of this data file, you could use `$1` in place of `$0` (systematically).   Also note that if one row is 28 and the next row is 9, the output value will be 19, not 29 (so you are not guaranteed that the data will be monotonically increasing after passing through this script).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, @Yacob, but one possibility might be to replace `if` with `while`.  If you're going to have many cases in the input where you need to do the loop, you'd do better with a calculation (multiply, divide, etc) than iterating (because you're basically adding enough lots of 10 to make the current row larger than the previous row, along the lines of `$0 += 10 * int((old - $0 + ff) / 10);`, where `ff` is a suitable fudge-factor which I've not sat down and worked out yet).