# Connect by prior implementation in Unix

Tags: unix

Thanks for looking into the query.
Trying to find a solution of Oracle connect by prior functionality in Unix.

Sample input file

```
ColA , ColB
Join  , Filter
Aggregate, Target
Filter , Aggregate
Source , Join
```

Requirement is that one record will be identified as start Row - (Here where ColA value is Source)
And now based on joining ColB and ColA value row orders will be sorted

So first row is

```
Source , Join
```

Second Row is where ColB value of First row is equal to ColA value of Second Row
So Second Row -

```
Join  , Filter
```

Third Row is where ColB value of Second row is equal to ColA value of Third Row
So Third Row -

```
Join  , Filter
```

With this logic output will be

```
ColA , ColB
Source , Join
Join  , Filter
Filter , Aggregate
Aggregate, Target
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Show us your even failed attempts

Comment: Why `Source` is your first record ?  Also, you check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782016/comparing-consecutive-rows-in-awk

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].